# Does the JavaFX MediaPlayer on Windows use hardware acceleration for playing back videos?

Tags: java, video, javafx, h.264, hardware-acceleration

I was asking this question because on Macs and on Linux, my app plays back videos really smooth. Also seeking is a lot smoother as well. We're also using mp4, h264 video codec.

I have a Windows laptop with the exact same hardware as my Linux laptop and playback is okay, but it isn't what it's like on my Linux machine and is definitely not as smooth as the Mac.

I have the `prism.verbose=true` system property set so I'm getting info from Prism whenever the app starts up.

Is there a way that I can tell for sure that hardware acceleration is being used from the output? Also is Prism the component that's responsible for deciding whether or not to use hardware acceleration during video playback?

This is the output from my Linux computer:

```
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw 
Using java-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2
    succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Maximum supported texture size: 16384
Maximum texture size clamped to 4096
Non power of two texture support = true
Maximum number of vertex attributes = 16
Maximum number of uniform vertex components = 16384
Maximum number of uniform fragment components = 16384
Maximum number of varying components = 128
Maximum number of texture units usable in a vertex shader = 16
Maximum number of texture units usable in a fragment shader = 16

Graphics Vendor: X.Org
       Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on AMD TURKS
        Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.5.9
```

And this is the output from the Windows computer:

```
Prism pipeline init order: d3d sw 
Using native-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Loading D3D native library ...
    succeeded.
D3DPipelineManager: Created D3D9Ex device
Direct3D initialization succeeded
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Maximum supported texture size: 16384
Maximum texture size clamped to 4096
OS Information:
    Windows 7 build 7601
D3D Driver Information:
    AMD Radeon HD 7570M
    \\.\DISPLAY1
    Driver aticfx64.dll, version 8.17.10.1242
    Pixel Shader version 3.0
    Device : ven_1002, dev_6841, subsys_17A9103C
    Max Multisamples supported: 4
```

And for completeness, the Mac computer's output:

```
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw 
Using native-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2
    succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.MacGLFactory
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Maximum supported texture size: 16384
Maximum texture size clamped to 4096
Non power of two texture support = true
Maximum number of vertex attributes = 16
Maximum number of uniform vertex components = 4096
Maximum number of uniform fragment components = 4096
Maximum number of varying components = 128
Maximum number of texture units usable in a vertex shader = 16
Maximum number of texture units usable in a fragment shader = 16
Graphics Vendor: ATI Technologies Inc.
      Renderer: AMD Radeon R9 M370X OpenGL Engine
       Version: 2.1 ATI-1.38.3
```

Comment: Have you updated the driver for your video card?  It should support d3d 11, it looks like you're using 9.

Comment: On the Windows machine that I got Prism's output off of, no I think so. But I do have other Windows machines that perform the same and I have made sure that their drivers are up the date.

Comment: It's strange.  I find windows to have superior graphics performance.  I haven't checked with media player since vlc uses less cpu on both linux and windows for my tests.

Comment: Hi @arjabbar, have you figured out how to check if hardware acceleration is enabled? I'm having a similar issue. Thanks.

Comment: Back when I was working on this app I remember making sure that hardware acceleration was enabled. I remember toggling it on and off to make sure there was a difference, and there was in fact a huge difference in performed, especially when seeking through the video.